# Get Profile picture using SKYPE4COM

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, skype, skype4com

Is this possible to display my  profile picture as well as my friends profile picture in a picturebox control?? Am using c# and SKYPE4COM. Any suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [command](http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#COMMANDS):

```
var cmd = new SKYPE4COMLib.Command();
cmd.Command = string.Format("GET USER {0} AVATAR 1 {1}", userHandle, rootedPathFileName);
var skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
skype.SendCommand(cmd);
```

For more information see [this link](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/how-to-get-the-profile-picture-of-users-using-skype4com-api-with/td-p/444063).

Comment: Thanks for your help... The link you posted help me... :-)

Answer (score 1):

For profile picture add url or button click and put username in textbox its simpel..!!

```
profilePictureUrl = "http://api.skype.com/users/" 
                       + textBox2.Text + "/profile/avatar";
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = profilePictureUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the GET USER AVATAR command](http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#COMMAND_GET_USER_AVATAR) it allows you to save the image.

You could then point the picturebox to the image file.

Information on how to execute commands by [using Skype4COM can be found here](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API/Skype4COM-What-is-it-and-what-can-it-do/m-p/8155)